# For multi-page forms where parent has to call validate() on child, how to manage state?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

To provide some context, I am working on building a multi-page form where each page is its own component that should re-render itself in response to (valid/invalid) user input and prevent the form to move to the next page for invalid inputs on current page. Since there is no two-way binding in React, I leveraged a shared context provider between parent-child and used a custom hook to access validation logic. In order to perform the validation checks from the parent I attach a reference to a function which I call inside the child by sending it via props. Each time the parent has to move to next page it simply calls the function that is pointed to by this reference.

Shared context:

```
class Role {
    id: string = '';
    description: string = '';
    tenure: string = '';
}

class Person {
    name: string = '';
    age: string = '';
    roles: Role[] = [];
}


export const SharedContextProvider: React.FC = ({children}) => {
    const [person, setPerson] = useState<Person>(new Person('', ''));

    const validateName = () => {
        let isValid = person.name !== '';
        return {isValid: () => isValid, error: () => isValid ? '' : 'Invalid Name'};
    };
    ...; // other validation methods here skipped

    const isValidSection = (errorSetters: Map<FIELDS, (error: string) => void>, validatorHelper: Map<FIELDS, Helper>) => {
        let isValidSection = true;
        errorSetters.forEach((setError, field) => {
            let validation = validatorHelper.get(field);
            if (!validation) {
                throw new Error('validation not defined!');
            }
            let isValidField = validation.isValid(); // check if field is valid
            isValidSection = isValidSection && isValidField;
            let error = validation?.error() || '';
            console.log('Validating', field, 'isValid:', isValidField, 'error:', error);
            let doSth = errorSetters.get(field)!!;
            doSth(error); // debugging
        });
        return isValidSection;
    }

    const personalDetailsValidator = (errorSetters: Map<FIELDS, (error: string) => void>) => {
        const validatorHelper = new Map<FIELDS, Helper>(
            [
                [FIELDS.NAME, validateName()],
                [FIELDS.AGE, validateAge()],
            ]
        );
        return {isValidSection: () => isValidSection(errorSetters, validatorHelper)};
    };

    const professionalDetailsValidator = (role: Role, errorSetters: Map<FIELDS, (error: string) => void>) => {
        const validatorHelper = new Map<FIELDS, Helper>(
            [
                [FIELDS.DESCRIPTION, validateRoleDescription(role)],
                [FIELDS.TENURE, validateTenure(role)],
            ]
        );

        return {isValidSection: () => isValidSection(errorSetters, validatorHelper)};
    };

    const data: SharedContextValue = {
        person,
        personalDetailsValidator,
        professionalDetailsValidator,
        setPerson
    };

    return <SharedContext.Provider value={data}>{children}</SharedContext.Provider>
}

const useSharedContext = () => {
    const context = useContext(SharedContext);
    if (context === undefined) {
        throw new Error('Cannot be undefined');
    }
    return context;
}
```

Parent

```
const App = () => {
    const [
        activeStepIndex, // controls page on the form
        setActiveStepIndex
    ] = React.useState(0);

    let isCurrentSectionValid: () => boolean; // reference to function

    const validationHandler = (validateSection: () => boolean) => {
        isCurrentSectionValid = validateSection;
    }

    return (
        <Wizard
            i18nStrings={{...}}
            onNavigate={({detail}) => {
                let isValidSection = isCurrentSectionValid();
                console.log('[isValidSection]', isValidSection);
                if (isValidSection) {
                    setActiveStepIndex(detail.requestedStepIndex)
                }
            }
            }
            activeStepIndex={activeStepIndex}
            steps={[
                {
                    content: <PersonalDetails validationHandler={validationHandler}/>
                },
                {
                    title: "Completed",
                    content: <Final validationHandler={validationHandler}/>,
                    isOptional: true
                },
            ]}
        />
    );
}
```

Child1

```
const PersonalDetails: React.FC<PersonalProps> = ({validationHandler}) => {
    const {person, personalDetailsValidator, setPerson} = useSharedContext();
    const [name, setName] = useState(person.name || '');
    const [age, setAge] = useState(person.age || '');
    const [nameErrorText, setNameErrorText] = useState<string>('');
    const [ageErrorText, setAgeErrorText] = useState<string>('');

    useEffect(() => {
        setPerson(new Person(name, age));
    }, [name, age]);

    const validator = personalDetailsValidator(new Map<FIELDS, (error: string) => void>([
        [FIELDS.NAME, setNameErrorText],
        [FIELDS.AGE, setAgeErrorText],
    ]));

    // store validation state for each child
    const rolesValidators: Map<string, () => boolean> = new Map<string, () => boolean>();
    const roleValidationHandler = ((validateSection: () => boolean, id: string) => {
        rolesValidators.set(id, validateSection);
    });

    validationHandler(() => {
        let isValidSection = validator.isValidSection();
        let areValidRoles = Array.from(rolesValidators.values()).map(item => item())
            .reduce((i, j) => i && j, true);
        console.log('isValidSection', isValidSection, 'areValidRoles', areValidRoles);
        return isValidSection && areValidRoles;
    });


    return (
        <Container
            header={
                <Header variant="h2">
                    Personal Info
                </Header>
            }
        >
            <SpaceBetween direction="vertical" size="l">
                <FormField label="Name" errorText={nameErrorText}>
                    <Input value={name} placeholder={'Enter Name'} onChange={({detail}) => {
                        setName(detail.value);
                    }}/>
                </FormField>
                <FormField label="Age" errorText={ageErrorText}>
                    <Input value={age} placeholder={'Enter Age'}
                           onChange={({detail}) => {
                               setAge(detail.value);
                           }}
                    />
                </FormField>
                {person.roles.map((role, index) =>
                    <ProfessionalDetails key={role.id} validationHandler={roleValidationHandler} role={role}/>)}
            </SpaceBetween>
        </Container>
    );
}
```

Child2:

```
const ProfessionalDetails: React.FC<ProfessionalProps> = ({validationHandler, role}) => {
    const [description, setDescription] = useState(role.description || '');
    const [tenure, setTenure] = useState(role.tenure || '');
    const [descriptionErrorText, setDescriptionErrorText] = useState<string>();
    const [tenureErrorText, setTenureErrorText] = useState<string>();
    const {professionalDetailsValidator} = useSharedContext();

    const validator = professionalDetailsValidator(role, new Map<FIELDS, (error: string) => void>([
        [FIELDS.DESCRIPTION, setDescriptionErrorText],
        [FIELDS.TENURE, setTenureErrorText],
    ]));

    validationHandler(() => {
        return validator.isValidSection();
    }, role.id);

    useEffect(() => {
        role.description = description;
        role.tenure = tenure;
        console.log('Updating role...', JSON.stringify(role));
    }, [role]);

    return (
        <Container
            header={
                <Header variant="h2">
                    Professional Info
                </Header>
            }
        >
            <SpaceBetween direction="vertical" size="l">
                <FormField label="Description" errorText={descriptionErrorText}>
                    <Input value={description} placeholder={'Enter Occupation'}
                           onChange={event => setDescription(event.detail.value)}/>
                </FormField>
                <FormField label="Tenure" errorText={tenureErrorText}>
                    <Input value={tenure} placeholder={'Enter Hobby'}
                           onChange={event => setTenure(event.detail.value)}/>
                </FormField>
            </SpaceBetween>
        </Container>
    );
}
```

Child1,Child2 is validated as expected in isolation. But for list of child2 components if previous states capture an error (for empty input) then the state is not reset when the error is rectified and the errors are retained preventing moving to the next page.

I had two questions:

1. Is this a sustainable approach to validate forms with deep nested components?
2. What are good patterns for parent-child communication in these situations?

Note: I cannot use Redux due to my company constraints. It has to be done via React Context/Hooks.

Comment: I am lacking some information to help you out. You are talking about nested components, but they don't seem to appear in your code. Could you elaborate a bit? And maybe show more code so that we can provide you with a clear solution? Thanks!

Comment: @GabrielPichot Reproduced the issue with this code. My app is bit more complex but the problem is same as this one I believe. I think the issue is that `roles` are being re-created every time but the validation handlers retain the logic for the old `roles` instead of the new ones.